# any open source tool for continuous K8s resource status retrieval

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any open-source tool or logic by which I can get the continuous status of K8s resources. For example if have 10 deployments running on my K8s cluster then I want to keep checking the current operational status of those deployments. Similarly, this will hold good for other resources like Replica sets, stateful sets, Daemon sets, etc.
Currently, I have a logic that is dependent on the specific deployment hence looking out on something which can be generic for all deployments.

Answer (score 1):

As **@rock'n rolla** correctly pointed out, `kubectl get -w` is a really easy way to get basic information about the state of different Kubernetes resources.

If you need a more powerful tool that can quickly visualize cluster health, you can use the [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) or one of the many  [alternatives](https://octopus.com/blog/alternative-kubernetes-dashboards).
Personally I like to use the [k8dash - Kubernetes Dashboard](https://github.com/indeedeng/k8dash#k8dash---kubernetes-dashboard) because it's really easy to install and we can fully manage the cluster via the `k8dash` web interface.

---

I will describe how you can install and use `k8dash`.

As described in the [k8dash - Getting Started](https://github.com/indeedeng/k8dash#getting-started) documentation, you can deploy `k8dash` with the following command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/indeedeng/k8dash/master/kubernetes-k8dash.yaml
```

To access `k8dash`, you must make it publicly visible using `Ingress` (see: [Running k8dash with Ingress](https://github.com/indeedeng/k8dash#getting-started)) or `NodePort` (see: [Running k8dash with NodePort](https://github.com/indeedeng/k8dash#running-k8dash-with-nodeport)).

After exposing the dashboard, the easiest way to log into it is to create  a dedicated service account (see: [Service Account Token](https://github.com/indeedeng/k8dash#service-account-token)).

Using `k8dash` UI dashboard is pretty intuitive, you can monitor `Nodes`, `Pods`, `ReplicaSets`, `Deployments`, `StatefulSets` and more. Real time charts help quickly track down poorly performing resources.

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. If you're into UI's, you might as well checkout `Lens` : https://k8slens.dev/

I installed it on my Mac with a single command using `brew` and is fairly straightforward to use thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of really simple ways to do this are using command like:

`kubectl get deployments -w`
or
`watch kubectl get deployments`

Comment: @Imran, does this answer your question?